# Does the spirit have the same form as his/ her body? And what are the rights for a spirit?

Tags: soul

I know that the spirit of a person remains in grave till the day of judgement. If a person die then the spirit will have the same form as his body? And the spirit can walk,talk and etc? Can a good spirit have the right to move or walk around the world? like for example, walking in any places while other people don't know about it or he can go also to his family while his family don't know he is here? Because, I was thinking that the bad spirit does not have right to know about anything except to wait for the angel to come and say that he is his bad deeds and will remain in his or her grave punished. Can to you tell me if I'm right or wrong? And, can you tell me any verse from Quran that says, that the good spirit/ ghost of a dead person, can walk around us even if we don't know his presence? Curiously ask. Oh, and can you tell if there is any mistake out there to edit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The spirit has left the realm of the world (dunya). It will not be moving or walking around the world. [There is no Islamic evidence to suggest so, for either the believer or disbeliever]. It will be taken by the Angels into the next realm (Al Barzakh) and follow the proceedings there.

That is where the spirit will be moving (by the lead of Angels). Refer to [Ibn Majah (4262)](https://sunnah.com/urn/1293650) which describes that the soul, both the soul of the good-doer and the evildoer, will ascend up to the Heavens and then descend in this period of Al Barzakh.

When brought back (descended), the soul will be questioned. Refer to [Abu Dawud (4753)](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/42/158) which describes the answers that the good soul will give. It will "talk" ie answer the questions. Furthermore, there is [evidence](https://islamqa.info/en/20820) that the souls there will speak to each other. But again, this will happen in Al Barzakh; it is not happening among/with the people of the Dunya.

Then it will wait in its prepared 'bed' in the grave until Judgement Day.

As for what the soul looks like, Allah knows best. We were given limited knowledge on the soul.

> ويسألونك عن الروح قل الروح من أمر ربي وما أوتيتم من العلم إلا قليلا (And they ask you, [O Muhammad], about the soul. Say, "The soul is of the affair of my Lord. And mankind have not been given of knowledge except a little") - Qur'an 17:85.

Comment: hmm, I though that if a spirit failed to answer the “Grave Questions”, will not be able to speak with other spirits in graveyard.

Comment: Yes, I was referring the good souls, as that is who the hadith show speaking to each other.

Comment: Oh, I hope that I will be a good believer, so that when I will become a spirit, I can move around graveyard or probably to walk everywhere in this world, such as visiting other cities and to talk with other spirits. And not only because of that, because my dream is, to reach to the highest place in Heaven without being punished.

Comment: Brother, you won't want to 'move around in the city' when you will have the gate of Paradise open and its aromas/scents reaching your grave [if you are a good soul, inshaAllah]. You will forget all about "cities" lol.